# I have a table that looks something like this:

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

tblCust

```
Gender

Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
```

And I want to update such that in place of male in want to set female and in place of female want to set male. But if I update say female to male.

```
update tblCust set
Gender = 'Male'
where Gender = 'Female'
```

All rows are now male, so I lose track of what data was originally female and originally male.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: is there any column that can differentiate if user is Male or Female?

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done in two steps, because updating one type will affect the other type.

You need to update both types in one query, using a `case` statement:

```
update tblCust set
gender = case gender when 'Female' then 'Male' else 'Female' end
```

If you had other genders, you would need a slight refinement:

```
update tblCust set
gender = case gender 
    when 'Female' then 'Male'
    when 'Male' then 'Female'
    else gender end -- leave unchanged if neither Male nor Female
```

Comment: @james Bohemian's answer involves running just 1 query, so the table would be scanned only once, making the process quicker. Three queries mean three table scans, and therefore a longer processing time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the way ... its an easy swapping

```
Update tblCust Set Gender='M' WHERE Gender='Male';
Update tblCust Set Gender='Male' WHERE Gender='Female';
Update tblCust Set Gender='Female' WHERE Gender='M';
```